# Printer Icons in Print Dialog Box

Tags: winapi, printing, dialog

I am using C++ and plain Winapi calls to display Print dialog box and it works fine. However the dialog box I get shows old printer icons compared to similar Print dialogs produced by other software. I wonder why.

Does anyone have an idea how to display the new printer icons as does MSVC dialog

Thanks a lot.

Here is how I display the Print Dialog in my application:

```
// Initialize the PRINTDLGEX structure
PRINTDLGEX  PrnDlgEx ;

PrnDlgEx.lStructSize = sizeof (PRINTDLGEX) ;
PrnDlgEx.hwndOwner = hwnd ;
PrnDlgEx.hDevMode  = NULL ;
PrnDlgEx.hDevNames = NULL ;
PrnDlgEx.hDC = NULL ;
PrnDlgEx.Flags = PD_HIDEPRINTTOFILE | PD_NOCURRENTPAGE | PD_NOPAGENUMS |
                 PD_NOSELECTION | PD_USEDEVMODECOPIESANDCOLLATE ;
PrnDlgEx.Flags2 = 0 ;
PrnDlgEx.ExclusionFlags = 0 ;
PrnDlgEx.nPageRanges = 0 ;
PrnDlgEx.nMaxPageRanges = 0 ;
PrnDlgEx.lpPageRanges = nullptr ;
PrnDlgEx.nMinPage = 1 ;
PrnDlgEx.nMaxPage = 0xFFFF ;
PrnDlgEx.nCopies  = 1 ;
PrnDlgEx.hInstance = NULL ;
PrnDlgEx.lpPrintTemplateName = NULL ;
PrnDlgEx.lpCallback = NULL ;
PrnDlgEx.nPropertyPages = 0 ;
PrnDlgEx.lphPropertyPages = NULL ;
PrnDlgEx.nStartPage = START_PAGE_GENERAL ;
PrnDlgEx.dwResultAction = 0 ;

HRESULT Result = PrintDlgEx (&PrnDlgEx) ;
```

Below is screen shoots for my Print dialog 1 and MS VC dialog 2.

[image: My Print Dialog with old icons]

[image: MS VC Print Dialog with modern icons]

Comment: Wild guess but can you try to add a manifest to your app enabling common controls and visual styles, etc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview

Comment: There are at least to ways to display that dialog (`PrintDlg` and `PrintDlgEx`). And either one takes a *lot* of parameters through `PRINTDLG` and `PRINTDLGEX` structure, respectively. With that, the question seems wildly underspecified. Can you fix that?

Comment: And Visual Studio almost certainly customizes its print dialog (as it does with most of its UI). But making a custom Print Dialog is not a trivial undertaking.

Comment: I already have visual style enabled as per MS Docs by the following code :    #pragma comment(lib,"comctl32.lib")
    #pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
    name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
    processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")  The displayed icons in Print Dialog are not affected by visual styles

Answer (score 0):

According to [Customizing the Print Dialog Box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/print-dialog-box#customizing-the-print-dialog-box).You can create the custom template by modifying the default template specified in the Prnsetup.dlg file. The control identifiers used in the default Print dialog template are defined in the Dlgs.h file.

Then use the [`PRINTDLG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-printdlga) structure to enable the template.